# Calculating Clebsh-Gordan coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, representation-theory

I'm reading about Clebsh-Gordan coefficients, and one of the sources gives such an equation to calculate coefficients for state $m=j_1+j_2-1$

$$|j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-1\rangle\approx J_-|j_1,j_2\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{j_2}{j_1+j_2}}|j_1,j_2-1\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{j_1}{j_1+j_2}}|j_1-1,j_2\rangle$$

so that coefficients are

$$\langle j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-1|j_1,j_2-1\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{j_2}{j_1+j_2}}$$

$$\langle j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-1|j_1-1,j_2\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{j_1}{j_1+j_2}}$$

However, I am not sure how it was derived from $J_-|j_1,j_2\rangle$.

Comment: You can find it by writing $J_- = J^{(1)}_- + J^{(2)}_-$, where $J^{(k)}_-$ acts over the angular momentum $k$. Use the standard formulas for the action of ladder operators and then normalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is simplest if one writes
$$
\vert j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2\rangle = \vert j_1j_1\rangle \vert j_2j_2\rangle \tag{1}
$$
where $\vert j_km_k\rangle$ is an angular momentum state for particle $k$.  In this notation the *total* angular momentum operators as sums 
$J_{x}=J_{1x}+J_{2x}$ *etc* where $J_{1x}$ acts only on states of the first particle, and $J_{2x}$ acts only on the states of the second particle.   More formally, one should have $J_x=J_{1x}\otimes \hat 1 + \hat 1\otimes J_{2x}$.

Thus, the ladder operators are $J_\pm = J_{1\pm}+J_{2\pm}$ and one can verify that the state in (1) is killed by $J_+$ and is an eigenstate of $J_z$ with eigenvalue $j_1+j_2$, identifying this (up to a phase which is chosen to be +1) as $\vert jj\rangle$ with $j=j_1+j_2$.

To get the state $\vert j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-1\rangle $, ladder down from $\vert j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2\rangle$:
\begin{align}
J_-\vert j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2\rangle &= \sqrt{2(j_1+j_2)}\vert j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-1\rangle \\
&= \left[J_{1-}\vert j_1j_1\rangle\right]\vert j_2j_2\rangle 
+ \vert j_1j_1\rangle \left[J_{2-}\vert j_2j_2\rangle\right]\, ,\\
&=\sqrt{2j_1}\vert j_1,j_1-1\rangle\vert j_2j_2\rangle 
+\sqrt{2j_2}\vert j_1j_1\rangle \vert j_2j_2-1\rangle
\end{align}
from which your expressions follows.

Note that the (unnormalized) state
$\sqrt{2j_2}\vert j_1,j_1-1\rangle\vert j_2j_2\rangle - \sqrt{2j_1}
\vert j_1j_1\rangle \vert j_2,j_2-1\rangle$ is killed by $J_+$ and an eigenstate of $J_z$ with eigenvalue $j_1+j_2-1$, and must be thus proportional to the state $\vert jj\rangle$ with $j=j_1+j_2-1$.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. What about next ladder down for $m=j_1+j_2-2$? Would it be $J_-|j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-1\rangle=\sqrt{2(j_1+j_2)-1}|j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-2\rangle=[J_{1-}|j_1 j_1-1]|j_2 j_2\rangle+|j_1 j_1\rangle [J_{2-}|j_2 j_2-1]$ ?

Comment: No and yes.  You have the right idea but you need to act on $a\vert j_1 j_1-1\rangle \vert j_2j_2\rangle + b\vert j_1j_1\rangle \vert j_2,j_2-1\rangle$ with the correct $a$ and $b$ that you found for $\vert j_1+j_2,j_1+j_2-1\rangle$, i.e. you need to act on the state with appropriate linear combinations of $\vert j_1m_1\rangle \vert j_2m_2\rangle$.

Comment: This way, I got coefficients $\sqrt\frac{j_1(2j_1-1)}{j_s(2j_s-1)}$ and $\sqrt\frac{j_2(2j_2-1)}{j_s(2j_s-1)} $, where $j_s=j_1+j_2$. Shouldn't the sum of their squares be 1 though?

Comment: There will be three terms because there are three ways to make $m_1+m_2=j_1+j_2-2$ if you account correctly for the ranges of $m_1$ and $m_2$.  Explicitly: $m_1=j_1, m_2=j_2-2$, $m_1=j_1-1,m_2=j_2-1$ and $m_1=j_1-2, m_2=j_2$.  Thus your $j_1+j_2-2$ states will be a combo of 3 pieces.